# How to resize images inside CSS Grid to make grid fit page width

Tags: css, css-grid

I am quite new to web dev and am currently learning HTML and CSS.

I want to create a portfolio page inside my website, and used for this matter a 3-column CSS Grid, which I would like to fit to page width and be centered. I managed to display the pictures as I want, with margins and all but I am stuck on one problem : my images are too big, which results in the CSS Grid being too big and diplaying outside the page. Images are all 1000x1000 px.

I want my CSS Grid to resize itself to fit to page width, while keeping its aspect. How do I achieve this ?

Here is the code for my CSS grid (named `artworkGrid`) :

```
.artworkGrid {
  display: inline-grid;
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  grid-gap: 5%;
  margin: 5%;
  max-width: 25%;
  grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;

}
```

Using `max-width: 25%` allowed me to get approximatively the page width, so it works but it's a kind of shady alternative way to do it. Also, it doesn't resize the pictures inside the grid.

I tried to resize the images themselves :

```
.artwork {
  width: auto;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you provide the html too with placeholder images. but you could change your `max-width: 25%;` to `max-width: 100vw` that way the maximum width would be 100vw = 100% of the view width (screensize)

Comment: Thanks Nico! It achieved exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem I've added it as an answer too!

Answer (score 0):

change

```
max-width: 25%;
```

to

```
max-width: 100vw
```

that way the maximum width would be 100vw = 100% of the view width (screensize)